# How to run an api request until a condition is met in c#

Tags: c#, restsharp, timespan

I'm new to C# and my purpose is to parse a value from an API call and keep on doing the call until that value is between `5` and `10` for that parameter.

I have successfully parsed that value from `valuez` and got the proper result in `finalresult`, now my problem is to make the call repeatedly until I reach the intended value bracket, I tried debugging the code below but when it reaches var timer the entire block is highlighted at once and not every line is accessed separately. I know the condition of stopping between 5 and 10 is not in the code below but it was supposed to run endlessly before i modify that part.

sample response

```
{{
"value1" : "input1",
"value2" : null,
"value3" : {"valuex" : 4,
"valuey" : 5,
"valuez" : 6}
"value4" : 17
}}
```

,

Code

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(Endpoint)
double finalresult = -1;

var startTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.Zero;
var periodTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async(e) =>
{
var client = new RestClient(options);
vsr request = new RestRequest();
var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
var requestContent = response.Content;
var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatusResponse>(responseContent);
finalresult = statusResponse.value3.valuez

}, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use a timer for this?

Comment: yes, I want the request sent every 1 minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
public async Task<double> GetValuez()
{
  var options = new RestClientOptions(Endpoint)
  double finalresult = -1;

  var startTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.Zero;
  var periodTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
  var client = new RestClient(options);

  while (true)
  {
    var request = new RestRequest();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
    var requestContent = response.Content;
    var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatusResponse>(responseContent);
    finalresult = statusResponse.value3.valuez

    if (finalresult >= 5 && finalresult <= 10) return finalresult;

    await Task.Delay(periodTimeSpan);
  }
}
```

It's a simple loop that will keep requesting until the condition is met.